# Change background color on hover of a CardView

Tags: android, selector, android-cardview

I want to change background color to my CardView in Android Studio, I want to use selector, but I dont know what I do

This in my code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_ordina"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/options"
                    android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/carrello"
                    android:tint="@color/background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/title"
                    android:text="ORDINA"
                    android:textColor="@color/background"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a selector and set the following attributes to your CardView.

```
android:foreground="@drawable/card_foreground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Here is the code for card_foreground.xml, add it in your project's **drawable** folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#e0F5AD6E"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#0f000000"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

You can change the state colors and radius according to your requirements. Now, when you click on the CardView the color will get changed.